# Separating Tkinters GUI and control of the application

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

**1) What is my goal:**
I’m creating an application that should read data every 60s from ModBusServer, append those data to Graphs and then when the app is closed save the data to excel file.

*Site note:
The process of reading data from ModBusServer and appending them to graphs should start after a start button is pressed. 
And end after stop button is pressed OR when ModBusServer sends a request to stop.*

**2) What I have so far:**
I created the GUI without any major problems as a class “GUI_komora”.
Everything there works just fine.

**3) What is the problem:**
But now I’m lost on how to approach the “read data every 60 seconds”, and overall how to control the application.

I did some research on threading but still I’m confused how to implement this to my application. 
I learned how to make functions run simultaneously in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU).
And also how to call a function every few seconds using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop/538559#538559).

But none of them helped me to learn how to control the overall flow of the application.

If you could redirect me somewhere or tell me about a better approach I would be really glad.

Some of my code:

```
from tkinter import *

from GUI_komora import GUI

root = Tk()
my_gui = GUI(root) #my GUI class instance

#main loop
root.mainloop()

"""

How do I achieve something like this???

whenToEnd = False
while whenToEnd:
    if step == "Inicialzation":
        #inicializace the app

    if step == "ReadData":
        #read data every 60 seconds and append them to graphs

    if step == "EndApp"
        #save data to excel file and exit app
        whenToEnd = True 


"""
```

Comment: How long does the code that reads the data take to execute? Does it run for several seconds, or just a few milliseconds? The answer will help define a proper solution. If it's just a couple hundred milliseconds or less, you don't need threading.

Comment: It is somewhere around one second. But there is a chance that it can sometimes be longer because the modbuserver is connected through ethernet.

Comment: How would I approach this problem without using threading? I really don't know ... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a loop that takes a decision (every 60 sec in your case) and pushes the outcome of the decision to tkinter GUI: https://github.com/shorisrip/PixelescoPy/blob/master/base.py
Parts:

1. main thread - starts tkinter window
2. control thread - reads some data and decides what to show in GUI
3. GUI class - has  a method "add_image" which takes input an image and displays on GUI.(add_data_to_graph maybe in your case). This method is called everytime by the control thread.

Snippets:

```
def worker(guiObj, thread_dict):
    # read some data and make decision here
    time.sleep(60)
    data_to_show = <outcome of the decision>
    while some_logic:
        pictureObj = Picture(chosen, timer)
        pictureObj.set_control_thread_obj(thread_dict["control_thread"])
        guiObj.set_picture_obj(pictureObj)
        pictureObj.display(guiObj)
        # do post display tasks
    guiObj.quit_window()

# Keep GUI on main thread and everything else on thread
guiObj = GuiWindow()
thread_list = []
thread_dict = {}
thread_for_image_control = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(guiObj,
                                                                 thread_dict))
thread_dict["control_thread"] = thread_for_image_control
thread_list.append(thread_for_image_control)
thread_for_image_control.start()
guiObj.run_window_on_loop()
# thread_for_image_control.join()
```

Code for Picture class:

```
class Picture:
    def __init__(self, path, timer):
        self.path = path
        self.timer = timer
        self.control_thread_obj = None

    def set_control_thread_obj(self, thread_obj):
        self.control_thread_obj = thread_obj

    def display(self, guiObj):
        image_path = self.path
        guiObj.add_image(image_path)
        time.sleep(self.timer)
```

Code for GUI class

```
class GuiWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.picture_obj = None
        self.root = Tk()
        self.image_label = None
        self.image = None
        self.folder_path = None
        self.timer = None
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.exit_button)

    def add_image(self, image_path):
        resized_img = self.resize(image_path)
        image_obj = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_img)
        image_label = Label(self.root, image=image_obj,
                            height=resized_img.height,
                            width=resized_img.width)
        self.image = image_obj # DO NOT REMOVE - Garbage collector error
        if self.image_label is not None:
            self.remove_image()
        image_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
        self.image_label = image_label
```

Here based on  my control loop thread I am changing image (in your case graph data) of the tkinter GUI.
Does this help?